# Why does set uuid = (select uuid()); update in mysql not work for this query?

Tags: mysql, uuid

```
UPDATE testtable SET uuid = (select uuid());
```

If i run this command in my local or CI database, it works but not in prod. Tables are identical in all databases.

Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Since i am only specifying a single column in the update query, I am at a loss to why it would complain about column count.

Is there any settings anyone in aware of that affects this? It works in other databases before prod.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Posting incase it helps another person.

There was a trigger in the prod database looking at the table... The error was coming from the trigger (an on update trigger).

Appreciate those who were thinking about this for me.